# Is it possible to test meteor packages with npm peer dependencies?

Tags: testing, meteor

I have an Atmosphere package that depends on `meteor-accounts-t9n`, an npm package.  [The guide recommends](https://guide.meteor.com/writing-atmosphere-packages.html#peer-npm-dependencies) that peer dependencies be used, if possible, and to do a runtime check for the dependency using `tmeasday:check-npm-versions`.

That works great for my main application, but when I try to run the tests on my package the dependency is not found:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'meteor-accounts-t9n'
at makeMissingError (modules-runtime.js?hash=b819d45cbf32aff410d740fac0364cb4088cd3f2:232)
at Module.require (modules-runtime.js?hash=b819d45cbf32aff410d740fac0364cb4088cd3f2:251)
at Module.moduleLink [as link] (modules.js?hash=655bc49ceeeeb29fd8970000aeef404082790b9b:302)
at at_error.js (at_error.js:1)
....
```

Is there a way to specify an npm peer dependency in package.js, its `onTest()` function, or somewhere else in the package?

Comment: For these kind of packages I always create a minimal Meteor project and add the package plus the targeted npm package and write/run the tests. I did not found an easier way yet.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround.  That's the best I can think of too, though I'm hoping to publish the package, and that would double the awkwardness.